# Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать алгоритм для решения задачи на с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не могу понять какой алгоритм нужно использовать для решения этой задачи:

> Имеется несколько романов одного писателя, для каждого из них известен объем (число страниц). Для издания сочинений романы надо сгруппировать в тома так, чтобы объем тома не превышал N страниц. Показать всевозможные варианты компоновки романов и выбрать вариант с минимальным количеством томов.

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, это вроде бы NP-полная задача... Если это Донцова или там Сименон — никакой перебор не пройдет, а для нормального писателя можно и перепробовать все (N-1)! перестановок... Только в реальности бывают еще и типа сериалов, a la "Хождение по мукам" из трех книг, которые разрывать очень нехорошо...

Comment: Если было бы просто "найти лучшую компоновку", было бы сложно. А раз просят еще и вывести все - то их в любом случае надо перебирать.

Comment: Для Донцовой это 240! вариантов - порядка 4e468... :) Долго же выводить придется )) @HolyBlackCat

Comment: По-хорошему, резко меньше. Потому что в пределах тома перестановка роли не играет. Тут надо что-то типа рекурсивного алгоритма — сначала все варианты для первого тома, не превышающие N страниц, потом из оставшихся для второго и так далее. Плюс минисокращение за счет того, что первый нераспределенный роман точно попадает в рассматриваемый том. Интересная задача, кстати... Что-то типа ветвления с отсечением.

Comment: Тут не принято портить свои вопросы после получения ответа. Они остаются для будущих читателей. (Ну и плюс, в [лицензионном соглашении](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) написано, что вы разрешаете SO демонстрировать все ваши вопросы/ответы, и не можете отозвать это право.)

Comment: Можно тупо в лоб перебирать все и собирать результаты, а потом выбрать лучший. Возможно есть способ эффективнее. Но там точно не обойдётся без глубоких знаний в математике.

Comment: Если бы число томов было задано, то можно было бы решать двойственную задачу: так распределить все произведения по K томам чтобы объём самого толстого тома был минимален. Это можно сделать полным перебором за *K^<число произведений>*. Теперь двоичным поиском по *K* отыщем минимальное число томов такое что объём тома меньше *N*. Сложность *logK * K^<число произведений>*.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант: генерировать все перестановки произведений, каждую перестановку разбить на всевозможные варианты томов. Минусы: тома с разным порядком произведений считаются разными томами, одинаковые тома в разном порядке считаются разными результатами.

Вариант реализации с перестановками через алгоритмы и рекурсивным разбиением на тома:

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<int, std::string> Book;
const int N = 300; //Максимум страниц
int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); //Минимальное число томов
std::vector<std::vector<Book>> result_seq; //Вектора с последовательностями томов
std::vector<std::vector<int>> result_indexes; //Вектора с индексами, обзначающими конец томов

//Вывод последовательности разбиения книг по томам
void show_seq(const std::vector<Book>& split_seq, const std::vector<int>& split_indexes) {
    auto it = split_indexes.begin();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < split_seq.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << split_seq[i].first << ' ' << split_seq[i].second << ' ';
        if (it != split_indexes.end() && *it == i) {
            std::cout << "| ";
            ++it;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}

//Разбиение последовательности книг на тома
void split_books(const std::vector<Book>& split_seq, const std::vector<int>& split_indexes = std::vector<int>()) {
    int split_pages_count = 0;
    
    for (int i = split_indexes.size() ? split_indexes.back()+1 : 0; i < split_seq.size(); ++i) {
        split_pages_count+=split_seq[i].first;
        if (split_pages_count > N) {
            return; //Том не последний. Все возможные варианты уже сгенерированы
        }
        auto temp_indexes = split_indexes;
        temp_indexes.push_back(i);
        split_books(split_seq, temp_indexes);
    }
    
    //Выход из цикла происходит только когда вся последовательность разбита на тома
    if (split_pages_count > 0) {
        show_seq(split_seq, split_indexes);
        if (split_indexes.size() < result) {
            result_seq.clear();
            result_indexes.clear();
            result_seq.push_back(split_seq);
            result_indexes.push_back(split_indexes);
            result = split_indexes.size();
        } else if (result == split_indexes.size()) {
            result_seq.push_back(split_seq);
            result_indexes.push_back(split_indexes);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Book> books = {{100, "title1"}, {200, "title2"}, {250, "title3"}, {50, "title4"}};
    
    std::sort(books.begin(), books.end()); //Перебор идёт в лексикографическом порядке
    do {
        split_books(books); //Разбиваем на тома
    } while (std::next_permutation(books.begin(), books.end())); //Генерируем следующую перестановку томов
    
    std::cout << "Minimum number of volumes:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < result_seq.size(); i++) {
        show_seq(result_seq[i], result_indexes[i]);
    }
}
```

Избавиться от минусов можно отбрасыванием тех вариантов, где произведения внутри томов идут не по возрастанию, и тех вариантов, где первые произведения в томах идут не по возрастанию:

```
void split_books(const std::vector<Book>& split_seq, const std::vector<int>& split_indexes = std::vector<int>(), const Book& prev_volume = Book{-1, ""}) {
    int split_pages_count = 0;
    int first_index = split_indexes.size() ? split_indexes.back() + 1 : 0;
    if (first_index < split_seq.size() &&  prev_volume > split_seq[first_index]) {
        return; //Тома идут не по возрастанию первых произведений.
    }
    for (int i = first_index; i < split_seq.size(); ++i) {
        split_pages_count+=split_seq[i].first;
        if (split_pages_count > N) {
            return; //Том не последний. Все возможные варианты уже сгенерированы
        }
        if (i > first_index && split_seq[i-1] > split_seq[i]) {
            return; //Произведения внутри тома не по возрастанию.
        }
        auto temp_indexes = split_indexes;
        temp_indexes.push_back(i);
        split_books(split_seq, temp_indexes, split_seq[first_index]);
    }

    //Выход из цикла происходит только когда вся последовательность разбита на тома
    if (split_pages_count > 0) {
        show_seq(split_seq, split_indexes);
        if (split_indexes.size() < result) {
            result_seq.clear();
            result_indexes.clear();
            result_seq.push_back(split_seq);
            result_indexes.push_back(split_indexes);
            result = split_indexes.size();
        } else if (result == split_indexes.size()) {
            result_seq.push_back(split_seq);
            result_indexes.push_back(split_indexes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Алгоритмическая бомба =) ставлю плюсик

Comment: А зачем для каждой перестановки еще и все варианты разбивки? Просто идем и набираем N страниц. Набрали - идем к следующему тому.

Comment: @Mikhailo, в задании сказано `всевозможные компоновки романов`. Т.о. вариант где каждое произведение находится в своём томе тоже считается вариантом компоновки.

Comment: Нумерация томов — это уже совершенно не относящийся к делу вопрос. Хотя тут есть другой интересный вопрос - порядок в пределах тома. Как я понимаю, он тоже не важен, а тогда все куда сложнее, чтоб этим воспользоваться как-то.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    #include 
#include 
#include

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N; // число романов
    cin >> N;

    vector<int> count_of_lists(N); // объемы романов
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> count_of_lists[i];
    }

    int max_lists; // максимальный объем тома
    cin >> max_lists;

    int min_tomes = N; // минимальное количество томов
    vector<int> best_var; // лучшая комбинация романов

    //НУ КОРОЧЕ ТУТ ПРОВЕРКА, ЧТО ЕСЛИ ЗАПИСАЛИ ТОМ, ТО ЧЕ ЕГО ЕЩЕ РАЗ ЗАПИСЫВАТЬ
    for (int i = 1; i < (1 << N); i++) {
        int sum_oflists = 0;
        vector<int> current_var;

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (i & (1 << j)) {
                // если j-й роман включен в текущую комбинацию
                sum_oflists += count_of_lists[j];
                current_var.push_back(j);
            }
        }

        if (sum_oflists <= max_lists && (N - static_cast<int>(current_var.size())) < min_tomes) {
            // проверка если комбинцаия не заполнена
            min_tomes = N - current_var.size();
            best_var = current_var;
        }
    }

    sort(best_var.begin(), best_var.end());

    // вывод лучшей комбинации
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(best_var.size()); i++) {
        cout << best_var[i] + 1 << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Тут только перебор, может и есть варианты записи размера томов в матрицу, но я не супер-крут в алгебре, поэтому решил задачу так. Если олимпиадные задачи решаете, значит побитовый сдвиг шарите.

`(i & (1 << j))` - если j != 0, то после побитового i все биты заполнятся нулями кроме бита j.

`(1 << N)` -> (i < pow(n, 2))

Comment: а там все комбинации вывести надо, ща сделаем

Comment: мне весь код придется перекопать, чтобы вывод сделать, а мне так не хочется его переделывать, но общая идея все равно такая будет, поэтому за ответ тоже считается.

Comment: ЧТО генерирует ваш генератор вариантов?

Comment: @MBo, входные данные такие:
1) Количество томов.
2) Количество страниц в каждом томе из количества томов.
3) Максимальное количество страниц в томах суммарное
Вывод:
Номера томов из которых получится максимальный и причем он будет самым коротким.

На вход:
5
100 150 300 400 250
500

Comment: Добавил скрин с выводом выше

Comment: Похоже, вы собираете один том, а задача в том, чтобы упаковать все книги в тома, причем томов должно быть минимальное количество

Comment: Ну тогда мне придется сделать ту же самую, только с динамическим количеством оставшихся томов.  Весь код логики выносим в функцию, а в main обрабатываем оставшиеся после каждого такого поиска тома, пока N != 0.

Comment: Сделать вектор с парами, где first = номер тома, second = количество страниц, если они добавляются в лучший вариант remove'аем их и перезапускаем для оставшихся, но нужно будет рассмотреть вариант, где размер одного тома больше чем максимальный, иначе мы улетаем в бесконечный цикл.